# Create a column in a dataframe with two levels spread randomly within the column's rows

Tags: r

I want to add a new column named `user_type` in my dataframe which will include the words `"active"` and `"inactive"` in a random way. I do not care how many `"active"` and `"inactive"` I will have and in which rows.

```
# Dummy data
data <- data.frame(
  int_end = as.Date("2017-06-14") - 0:364,
  users = runif(365) + seq(-140, 224)^2 / 10000,
  user_type=()
)
```

Comment: `user_type = ifelse( runif(365) > 0.5, "active", "inactive")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sample` -

```
data <- data.frame(
  int_end = as.Date("2017-06-14") - 0:364,
  users = runif(365) + seq(-140, 224)^2 / 10000,
  user_type=sample(c('active', 'inactive'), 365, replace = TRUE)
)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
library(dplyr)
data <- data %>%
  mutate(user_type = sample(c("active","inactive"),size = nrow(data),replace = T))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `sample` in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, user_type := sample(c("active", "inactive"),
     size = .N, replace = TRUE)]
```